# LED Cinema Display Calibration

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, display, led, calibration

I have recently bought an Apple 27" LED Cinema Display and am using this with a late 2008 unibody MacBook Pro. The display is working well, however some of the colours seem slightly "off" to me. Blue links in sites like Reddit and Google look slightly more towards purple rather than blue, and yellows seem to have a slight green tinge.

I have tried using the calibration tool, and done so to the best of my ability, however it seems to make little or no difference.

Does anyone have some advice on where I can go from here? I have tried downloading an ICC file for the 27" iMac, however I can't seem to find out how to load this so I can see the difference. Is there also the possibility that the monitor is defective and I need to get a new one? Finally, is it even sensible to try an ICC someone else's monitor or does it depend more than on just the hardware?

Many thanks,
Amar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are certain it looks odd, get it replaced.  But first, try using a different DisplayPort cable and, if possible, another computer.

[Here's how to install ICC profiles on MacOSX.](http://www.bartneck.de/2009/09/11/install-an-icc-color-profile-on-mac-os-x/)

But if you do print or photography work, you should get a [Spyder Monitor Calibrator](http://www.datacolor.eu/en/products/monitor-calibration/spyder3elite/index.html).

I have an older version.  You can find them in eBay for reasonable prices.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried with some different profiles, and some of them are way off so it appears to be a monitor specific thing. I will goto the local Apple store and do a comparison, either it looks odd or it's just me! Thanks for the help

Comment: @amarsuperstar: I just added the suggestion to try another cable first.